# Using SED to insert a line, into a file, at a line specified by a variable

Tags: bash, sed

## This code will add "Hello World" to the 2nd line of text within the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

LineOfText="Hello World"
FileName="/tmp/textfile.txt"
printf "sentence one \n sentence two \n sentence three \n" > $FileName

sed -i "2i $LineOfText" $FileName

cat $FileName
```

textfile.txt before:

```
sentence one
sentence two
sentence three
```

textfile.txt after:

```
sentence one
Hello World
sentence two
sentence three
```

## I'm trying to set the "line number" as a variable.

```
## Incorrect. but similar to:

LineNum="2"
sed -i "$LineNumi $LineOfText" $FileName
```

Comment: ```$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | sed '2i foo'
sed: 1: "2i foo": command i expects \ followed by text``` . Not all sed are gnu sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `$LineNum` by `{}`:

```
sed -i "${LineNum}i $LineOfText" $FileName
```

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hair out lastnight.